# Symfony routing rule doesn't work without script name

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am trying to run symfony project on localhost. My url is: http://hmh/index/newyork/london.php. ".php" is suffix (it is always added to a url). The routing rule that is supposed to handle the url is:

```
distance:
  url:   /index/:from/:to/*
  param: { module: main, action: distance, template: distance,sf_culture: en }
```

Unfortunately, it works only when I specify script name: http://hmh/index.php/index/newyork/london.php. Otherwise default rule is used.

Do you have any idea why it acts so strangely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just copied content of httpd.conf from Symfony [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/03-Running-Symfony) and it worked. Must have been some server misconfiguration.